# Using fnReloadAjax Still not working

Tags: ajax, datatables

Using Datatables, and the fnReloadAjax plugin (see below), I am trying to reload the table's data from a server-side script using the following code:

```
$.fn.dataTableExt.oApi.fnReloadAjax = function(oSettings, sNewSource, fnCallback, bStandingRedraw) {
            if (sNewSource !== undefined && sNewSource !== null) {
                oSettings.sAjaxSource = sNewSource;
            }

            // Server-side processing should just call fnDraw
            if (oSettings.oFeatures.bServerSide) {
                this.fnDraw();
                return;
            }

            this.oApi._fnProcessingDisplay(oSettings, true);
            var that = this;
            var iStart = oSettings._iDisplayStart;
            var aData = [];

            this.oApi._fnServerParams(oSettings, aData);

            oSettings.fnServerData.call(oSettings.oInstance, oSettings.sAjaxSource, aData, function(json) {
                /* Clear the old information from the table */
                that.oApi._fnClearTable(oSettings);

                /* Got the data - add it to the table */
                var aData = (oSettings.sAjaxDataProp !== "") ?
        that.oApi._fnGetObjectDataFn(oSettings.sAjaxDataProp)(json) : json;

                for (var i = 0; i < aData.length; i++) {
                    that.oApi._fnAddData(oSettings, aData[i]);
                }

                oSettings.aiDisplay = oSettings.aiDisplayMaster.slice();

                that.fnDraw();

                if (bStandingRedraw === true) {
                    oSettings._iDisplayStart = iStart;
                    that.oApi._fnCalculateEnd(oSettings);
                    that.fnDraw(false);
                }

                that.oApi._fnProcessingDisplay(oSettings, false);

                /* Callback user function - for event handlers etc */
                if (typeof fnCallback == 'function' && fnCallback !== null) {
                    fnCallback(oSettings);
                }
            }, oSettings);
        };
        $(document).ready(function() {


                $('#reloadDataBtn').click(function() {
                    $('#myTable').fnReloadAjax('mySource2.php');
                });


            $("#myTable").dataTable({ bSort: true,
                "bProcessing": true,
                "sAjaxSource": 'mySource1.php',
                bAutoWidth: true,
                "iDisplayLength": 5, "aLengthMenu": [5, 10, 25, 50, 100], 
                "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
                "aoColumnDefs": [{ "bSortable": false, "aTargets": [-1, 0]}]
            });
        });
```

But I still get the fnReloadAjax is not a function JS error. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because you address an element returned by jQuery, not the dataTable object itself.

Do this instead :

```
var dataTable; //reference to your dataTable

$('#reloadDataBtn').click(function() {
    dataTable.fnReloadAjax('mySource2.php');
    //NOT
    //$('#myTable').fnReloadAjax('mySource2.php');
});

dataTable = $("#myTable").dataTable({ 
  bSort: true,
  "bProcessing": true,
  "sAjaxSource": 'mySource1.php',
  bAutoWidth: true,
  "iDisplayLength": 5, "aLengthMenu": [5, 10, 25, 50, 100], 
  "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
  "aoColumnDefs": [{ "bSortable": false, "aTargets": [-1, 0]}]
});
```

Now `fnReloadAjax()` will be called proplerly.

Answer (score 5):

In verstion 1.10 of DataTable plugin, function *fnReloadAjax* is deprecated, now you need use **api().ajax.reload()** instead:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var datatable = $('#calls_list_table').dataTable({
        "iDisplayLength": 10,
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "ajax": {
            "url": "/calls/data/",
            "type": "POST"                

        }
    });

    $('button').click(function() {
        // use it instead of fnReloadAjax            
        datatable.api().ajax.reload();
    });
});
```

Comment: datatable.ajax.reload() will do.

Comment: datatable.api().ajax.reload() is for dataTable() init, datatable.ajax.reload() will work on DataTable() init (1.10+).